# Having some trouble with XPATH

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath

Here's the XML I'm reading:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ns10:UtilityData xmlns:ns10="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message" xmlns="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/RateBase/utility" xmlns:ns11="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/cross" xmlns:ns12="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/compact" xmlns:ns13="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/structure" xmlns:ns14="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/utility" xmlns:ns15="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/query" xmlns:ns16="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns:ns2="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/FFBase/utility" xmlns:ns3="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/FF/utility" xmlns:ns4="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/FFMetadata/utility" xmlns:ns5="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/FFMethod/utility" xmlns:ns6="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/FFRange/utility" xmlns:ns7="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/FFTarget/utility" xmlns:ns8="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/common" xmlns:ns9="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/generic">  
  <ns10:Header>...</ns10:Header>  
  <DataSet> 
    <Series xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" AVAILABILITY="A" DECIMALS="2" DISCLAIMER="G" FF_METHOD="D" TIME_FORMAT="P1D" xsi:type="ns5:SeriesType">  
      <ns6:Key> 
        <FREQ>D</FREQ>  
        <RATE>FF</RATE>  
        <MATURITY>O</MATURITY>  
        <ns2:FF_SCOPE>D</ns2:FF_SCOPE> 
      </ns6:Key>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-24</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-21</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-20</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs LAST_DAY_OF_MAINTENANCE_PERIOD="true" OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-19</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-18</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-17</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-14</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-13</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-12</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-11</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.15</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-10</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-07</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-06</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs LAST_DAY_OF_MAINTENANCE_PERIOD="true" OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-05</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-04</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-08-03</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-31</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.08</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-30</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-29</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-28</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-27</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.14</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-24</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.13</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-23</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.13</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs LAST_DAY_OF_MAINTENANCE_PERIOD="true" OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-22</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.13</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs>  
      <ns3:Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A"> 
        <TIME_PERIOD>2015-07-21</TIME_PERIOD>  
        <OBS_VALUE>0.13</OBS_VALUE> 
      </ns3:Obs> 
    </Series> 
  </DataSet> 
</ns10:UtilityData>
```

What I want is the individual pairs of "TIME_PERIOD" and "OBS_VALUE", which represents a date and a value (as seen).

I kept using online XPATH testers and got no results when doing '/ns10:UtilityData/DataSet' - which I assumed would return that entire structure underneath.

What should the correct XPATH look like?

Comment: Online XPath testers don't usually work well with documents that set a default namespace, as yours does with the `xmlns="http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/RateBase/utility"` on the root element.  That puts `DataSet` into a namespace, and your XPath is looking for a no-namespace `DataSet`.

Comment: It looks like there is about 16 separate namespaces defined in this document. Is there an easy way to get to the nodes I want without dealing with those? I'm going to be doing this in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a namespace with `namespace-uri`:

```
//*[local-name()='Obs' and namespace-uri()='http://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/schemas/FF/utility']
```